# what does this notation means in group theory?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Quoting from my text, "Observe that if we let $$\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$$ denote all ordered pairs of real numbers,....."
What does the notation "$\times$" means?

Comment: It means "direct product"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily, the $\times$ denotes the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), which, as your text explains, is the set of all ordered pairs of real numbers. In general the Cartesian product of two sets $X$ and $Y$ denotes the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

Since your tagged your question "group theory", I should mention that the $\times$ also has a related but separate meaning in terms of groups. If $G$ and $H$ are groups, then $G\times H$ can be given its own group structure, and the result is called the [direct product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups) of $G$ and $H$. In this case, the underlying set of $G\times H$ is precisely the ordinary Cartesian product but the set also inherits a group operation through $$(g_1,h_1)*_{G\times H}(g_2,h_2)=(g_1*_Gg_2,h_1*_Hh_2),$$
where $*_G,\ *_H,\ *_{G\times H}$ denotes the group product $G,\ H$ and $G\times H$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly ambiguous.

The [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two sets $A$ and $B$ is written $A \times B$ and means the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ is in $A$ and $b$ is in $B$.

The [direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups) of two groups $A$ and $B$ is *also* written as $A \times B$. The direct product is a group $(A \times B, \cdot)$, where the set is the Cartesian product of $A$ and $B$, and the operation is defined to act separately on $A$ and $B$: $(a_1,b_1)\cdot(a_2,b_2)=(a_1\cdot a_2,b_2\cdot b_2)$.

There are other ways you can combine groups as well, like the [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Properties).